# typescript show array data

Tags: reactjs, typescript

react use typescript  and set some imge file to useState

first, i set direct

```
<div>
{img[0]}
</div>
```

web page view

```
<div>   'string =>'<img src={require("../../asset/images/img_picture4.png")} alt=" "/></div>
```

my some api get image list from data base
then i show image list

and i change like this

```
const[img,setImgs]=useState()
 const imgArray:any = [
            {
                key: 'uniqueid1',
                src: '../../asset/images/img_picture4.png',
            },
            {
                key: 'uniqueid1',
                src: '../../asset/images/img_picture2.png',
            },

        ];


        setImgs(imgArray)

   console.log(img[0].src)
```

but img occur TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

how can show image list from my data base?

Comment: Please add minimal example

Comment: You didn't give `useState` a type or initial value. You can probably use `useState<{ key: string; src: string; }[]>([]);` to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says `TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'` because state is initially empty.

- If `useState` starts empty explicitly declare what type it is.
- Or if state never changes then there is no need to use `useState`.

```js
  const [img, setImg] = useState<any>();
```

- Use the `useEffect` hook if you want state to be updated on changes to state.
- Don't have setter `setImg` called in the global environment as it will start an infinite loop.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setImg(imgArray);
  }, [img]);
```

- Set conditional case for when the initial state is empty.
- React is unable to render whole Object types.
- You need to map the Object to JSX.

```js
  return (
      <div>
        {img ? imgArray.map((img) => <SomeComponent props={img}/>) : ""}
      </div>
  );
```

Comment: Please do not encourage the use of `any` where it is not necessary. We can use the type `{ key: string; src: string }[]` here based on OP's code.